# Read files in Azure blob storage from C#

Tags: c#, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have in Azure Storage a Blob Container, then a folder, then a subfolder, and then different files(`ContainerName/Folder1/Subfolder1/files...`).
How can I read all the files in that `Subfolder1` directory? Let's say I have some pdf files in there and I need to get them in my application, how would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to read the contents of the files or just list them? Also please tell us if the container ACL is set as Private or not?

Comment: For the moment I just want to list them, the container ACL is private. I have tried with `ListBlobs()` using the container reference but it only lists the folders of the fitst level(Folder1, Folder2, etc, not Subfolder1... etc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855853/how-to-get-all-files-from-a-directory-in-azure-blob-using-listblobssegmentedasyn/51893352#51893352 you can try this way as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's not really a subfolder, it's just a path.

As the [documentation for ListBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobs_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) says:

> You can optionally specify a blob prefix to list blobs whose names begin with the same string. If you use a delimiter character in your blob names to create a virtual directory structure, the blob prefix can include all or part of the virtual directory structure (but not the container name).

So you would use pass in `Folder1/Subfolder1` as the prefix:

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
foreach (var file in container.ListBlobs(prefix: "Folder1/Subfolder1", useFlatBlobListing: true))
{ 
    // etc
```

Note: I do not remember offhand whether the prefix needs a leading or trailing slash or both or neither..

`prefix` parameter ensures that only blobs names of which start with the parameter's value will be returned as part of listing. `useFlatBlobListing` parameter will ensure that if there are any blobs in the nested folders inside the subfolder specified in prefix are also returned.

Comment: You just beat me by a minute :). Is it OK if I update your answer? There's one bit more information I want to provide.