# How to get all files from a directory in Azure BLOB using ListBlobsSegmentedAsync

Tags: c#, azure, containers, blob, azure-blob-storage

While trying to access all files of the Azure blob folder, getting sample code for `container.ListBlobs();` however it looks like an old one.

Old Code : `container.ListBlobs();`

New Code trying :    `container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);`

I am trying to use the below code :

```
container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
```

Folders are like :

```
Container/F1/file.json
Container/F1/F2/file.json
Container/F2/file.json
```

Looking for the updated version to get all files from an Azure folder.
Any sample code would help, thanks!

Comment: If the my answer is helpful, you can mark it as answer to help other community members find the helpful information quickly, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**:
Getting all files name from a directory with **Azure.Storage.Blobs v12** - Package

```
var storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...........=core.windows.net";
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString);

//get container
var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container_name");

List<string> blobNames = new List<string>();

//Enumerating the blobs may make multiple requests to the service while fetching all the values
//Blobs are ordered lexicographically by name
//if you want metadata set BlobTraits - BlobTraits.Metadata
var blobHierarchyItems = container.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, "/");

await foreach (var blobHierarchyItem in blobHierarchyItems)
{
    //check if the blob is a virtual directory.
    if (blobHierarchyItem.IsPrefix)
    {
        // You can also access files under nested folders in this way,
        // of course you will need to create a function accordingly (you can do a recursive function)
        // var prefix = blobHierarchyItem.Name;
        // blobHierarchyItem.Name = "folderA\"
        // var blobHierarchyItems= container.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, "/", prefix);     
    }
    else
    {
        blobNames.Add(blobHierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
    }
}
```

There are more option and example you can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet#use-a-hierarchical-listing).

This is the [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) to the nuget package.

Answer (score 8):

C# code:

```
   //connection string
    string storageAccount_connectionString = "**NOTE: CONNECTION STRING**";

    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("**NOTE:NAME OF CONTAINER**");
    //The specified container does not exist

    try
    {
        //root directory
        CloudBlobDirectory dira = container.GetDirectoryReference(string.Empty);
        //true for all sub directories else false 
        var rootDirFolders = dira.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, null, null, null, null).Result;

        foreach (var blob in rootDirFolders.Results)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Blob", blob);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //  Block of code to handle errors
        Console.WriteLine("Error", e);

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code for the Answer :

```
private async Task<List<IListBlobItem>> ListBlobsAsync(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    List<IListBlobItem> results = new List<IListBlobItem>();
    do
    {
       bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
       BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.None;
       int maxBlobsPerRequest = 500;
       var response = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(BOAppSettings.ConfigServiceEnvironment, useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, maxBlobsPerRequest, continuationToken, null, null);
            continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
            results.AddRange(response.Results);
        }
     while (continuationToken != null);
     return results;
}
```

And then you can return values like:

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> listBlobs = await this.ListBlobsAsync(container);
foreach(CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob in listBlobs)
  {
     BOBlobFilesViewModel boBlobFilesViewModel = new BOBlobFilesViewModel
     {
          CacheKey = cloudBlockBlob.Name,
          Name = cloudBlockBlob.Name
      };
      listBOBlobFilesViewModel.Add(boBlobFilesViewModel);
   }
//return listBOBlobFilesViewModel;
```

Answer (score 3):

The method `CloudBlobClient.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` is used to return a result segment containing a collection of blob items in the container.

To list all blobs, we can use `ListBlobs` method,

Here is a demo for your reference:

```
    public static List<V> ListAllBlobs<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> expression, string containerName,string prefix)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("YourConnectionString;");

        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        var list = container.ListBlobs(prefix: prefix,useFlatBlobListing: true);

        List<V> data = list.OfType<T>().Select(expression.Compile()).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

**Usage and screenshots:**

List all blobs' names under one folder:

[image: list all blobs' names under one folder]

List all blobs' URLs under one folder:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I resolved it using ListBlobsSegmentedAsync and my custom logic, 
 however, ListBlobs is no more in use as far as I have tried.. :)

Comment: ListBlobs is depreciated and removed from Azure SDK.